# Windows Server 2003 hangs when I plug in any external drive. How can I prevent this?

Tags: usb, windows-server-2003, drive-letter

I have to back up a 50 gig file to an external drive weekly. If I plug it into USB, the server hangs (nonresponsive explorer etc). Tried 2 different drives with same result.

Googling suggests this is due to the drive getting assigned a drive letter that's already taken. If that's correct, how can I work around it? Right now I'm transferring the file over the network... takes forever. I tried booting with the drive plugged (works ok) and assigning it a high drive letter, but if I unplug and replug it, it hangs again. I want to be able to do this every week without rebooting the server.

Comment: Have you tried other USB drives in the 2003 machine? How about trying the drive on a different machine? This will help narrow down if it's the drive or the computer with the problem.

Comment: howdy... I did try 2 different drives with the same result, and both drives plug into a modern windows 7 PC with no issue. 

I think it's the operating system, I've seen other people with similar issues say it's windows getting hung up assigning the drive letter to the new drive. What I haven't seen is a working fix for this.

Comment: I am seeing the same with a thumb drive. I have MSE disabled (it was enabled). I see an EventID 51 "Erorr detected on device \Device\Harddisk1" when it happens. In theory - this is an existing drive with an assigned letter. The thumb drive sometimes works with the server, but once in this state - stays in it for a while.

Comment: You could try to find the drive letter used in the registry and change / delete it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223188 , http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/266874-45-drive-letter-assignments-registry